# Numbers Between 2 Columns of Integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
NumDf = {'Num1' : [5,7,5,5,5,5,8,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,6], 'Num2' : [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]}
NumDf = pd.DataFrame(NumDf)
NumDf

NumDf['Num1'] <= int(input('Input your number')) <= NumDf['Num2']
# the above code gives me an error
```

My goal is to produce another column in NumDf that has True/False values for the above equation.  I would then filter NumDf for all True values.

Note: The above equation gives me errors.  I'm looking for a True if the entered number by the user is between Num1 and Num2 for all rows of the data frame.  Example: If a user enters number 6, it would be True for the first row of the data frame, but it would be False for the second row.

Comment: Trying not to do a 'for' statement.

Comment: _"The above equation gives me errors"_: What errors? You should include all the relevant information in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your test value into a variable, and then create a new column as the `and` of the two conditions:

```
test = int(input('Input your number'))
NumDf['test'] = (NumDf['Num1'] <= test) & (NumDf['Num2'] >= test)
```

For example, if the input was 6 the result would be:

```
    Num1  Num2   test
0      5    10   True
1      7    10  False
2      5    10   True
3      5    10   True
4      5    10   True
5      5    10   True
6      8    10  False
7      5    10   True
8      5    10   True
9      5    10   True
10     5    10   True
11     5    10   True
12     9    10  False
13     5    10   True
14     5    10   True
15     5    10   True
16     5    10   True
17     6    10   True
18     5    10   True
19     5    10   True
20     6    10   True
```

Answer (score 3):

You get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

because in python, `a <= b <= c` is syntactic sugar for `(a <= b) and (b <= c)`.

Applying that to your case, you are effectively doing

```
(NumDf['Num1'] <= something) and (something <= NumDf['Num2'])
```

Now, `NumDf['Num1'] <= something` gives you a *series* of booleans, as does `(something <= NumDf['Num2'])`. The implementation of the *logical* `and` operator for a `pandas.Series` doesn't know what to do with `(a and b)` when either of those two are themselves `pandas.Series` objects, and so it throws that error.

The solution is to use the *bitwise* `and` operator, which performs the operation element-wise on the two `Series`. Of course, since you're going to have to execute two separate comparisons, you're going to have to ask for the input *before* you do these comparisons.

```
>>> num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
>>> (NumDf['Num1'] <= num) & (num <= NumDf['Num2'])

0      True
1     False
2      True
...
18     True
19     True
20     True
dtype: bool
```